# Pig Latin Sentence Converter

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying a program that translates your sentence into pig latin. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class PigLatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Enter text in the quotes of System.ot.println(covertToLatin(" "));
        System.out.println(covertToLatin("Type your sentence here."));
    }

    private static String covertToLatin(String string) {
        String end = "";
        String delims = "\\s+";
        String[] words = string.split(delims);
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(isVowel(words[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0))) {
                end += words[i] + "ay";
            } else {
                end += words[i].substring(1) + words[i].substring(0, 1) + "ay";
            }
        }
        return end;
    }

    private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        if (c == 'a')
            return true;
        if (c == 'e')
            return true;
        if (c == 'i')
            return true;
        if (c == 'o')
            return true;
        if (c == 'u')
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

It translates "Type your sentence here." to "ypeTayouryayentencesayere.hay" I am stumped as to finding a way to translate my whole sentence. can you please help me translate a whole sentence into pig latin? Also, it would help if you could find a way to make the sentence convert in all caps too.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused as to what your problem is.  What is not working as you want?

Comment: Isn't it working, just without spaces?  If I clean up your output, it is reasonable pig latin: `ypeTay ouryay entencesay ere.hay`.  I think you just need to add spaces between the words.

Comment: It looks like your result is almost correct, except for a few flaws.  You should be able to fix those.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am looking to translate a sentence in pig latin and have the words spaced out and displayed in CAPS. My program only translates the words but does not space them out and it does not print the results in CAPS.

Answer (score 1):

for upper case, use `String.toUpperCase()` function

Answer (score 0):

Start by translating one word first and then a complete sentence. For example STACK should print out ACKSTAY. Your program prints out TACKSAY.
Why is this? Let's look at your logic:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        if(isVowel(words[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0))) {
                            end += words[i] + "ay";
                        } else {
   /*substring(1) is always 1 &&
  you add substring(0,1) which is always the interval (0,1) they never change*/

          end += words[i].substring(1) + words[i].substring(0, 1) +ay";
           }
       }
     return end.toUpperCase();
                }

            private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
                if ((c == 'a') | (c == 'e') | (c == 'i') | (c == 'o') | (c == 'u'))
                    return true;
               return false;
               }
```

Try writing your algorithm on paper first. For example always using the word stack.

First letter is an s (not a vowel) let's save it in a temp string.
second letter is t ( not a vowel) let's save it in a temp string.
a is a vowel! we print from a onwards + letters in temp + ay

end result = "ack" + "st" + "ay"

abstracting --> substring(i, endOfString) + substring(k,i) + "AY

so you actually need two counters! i,k used to print substring(i,EndOfString) and substring(i,k) which represents the temp array